# Apache Ignite - Pool size in Executor

Tags: ignite

I am trying to use cluster based executor service.

// Get cluster-enabled executor service. 
ExecutorService exec = ignite.executorService();

Is there anyway to set the number of threads in the executor service pool?

Hope, Jobs will be executed in each node in a cluster in a round robin fashion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs submitter to distributed executor service are executed in a public thread pool. Its size can be configured via `IgniteConfiguration.publicThreadPoolSize` configuration property. Note that the size is specified per node.

Comment: Will the jobs submitted thru this executor service be running in the same Node, or it will be running in any node.?

Comment: On any node, in round-robin fashion by default. It's actually based on Compute Grid under the hood, so any load balancing/failover/etc. are applied here as well. See this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid