# Executor service configuration (number of threads on each node)

Tags: java, executorservice, ignite

I'm intending to use cluster aware ignite [ExecutorService](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/executor-service). 
Documentation says:

> Ignite provides a cluster-enabled implementation of ExecutorService
>   and automatically executes all the computations in load-balanced
>   fashion within the cluster.

I would like to have the ability to execute tasks in parallel on each node. I would like to configure the number of thread the `ExecutorService` run on each node. Since ignite

```
ExecutorService exec = ignite.executorService();
```

has no parameters it's reasonable to ask how to configure that.

Comment: It was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960996/apache-ignite-pool-size-in-executor